# What is the difference of @Object vs Pointer( Object )?

Tags: delphi

I was testing this following code:

```
type
  TPersonA = class
    public
      procedure Speak;virtual;
  end;

  TPersonB = class
    public
      procedure Speak;virtual;
  end;
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var PersonA: TPersonA;
    PersonB : TPersonB;
begin
  PersonA := TPersonA.Create;
  PersonB := TPersonB.Create;

  PersonA := Pointer( PersonB );
  PersonA.Speak;
end;

procedure TPersonA.Speak;
begin
  ShowMessage('Hello');
end;


procedure TPersonB.Speak;
begin
  ShowMessage('Hello again');
end;

end.
```

So if i run this code with methods as virtual and pass a pointer of PersonB to PersonA and call the Speak, PersonB.Speak is executed.

However, if i delete the virtual directive in both methods and run again then delphi executes the method of PersonA as static, cause it's adress will be compiled directly into the code at the place it was called.

So, when both methods were declared as virtual and i changed the code:

PersonA := Pointer( PersonB ) ==>  PersonA := @PersonB

I got into a access violation. I think was doing in the first case a pointer of pointer but i've gotten confuse with the usage of @ in that case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A variable whose type descends from `TObject` is actually a pointer to the instance.

So `Pointer(PersonB)` is also pointer to the instance. But `@ObjectB` is the address of a pointer to the instance. That is there is an extra level of indirection.

FWIW both of these two options are meaningless and will not lead anywhere useful.

As for the different behaviour when you remove the `virtual` directive, a virtual method is dispatched using the runtime type of the instance, a non-virtual method is dispatched using the compile time type of the instance variable. The fact that the code runs at all is due to the two unrelated classes having compatible VMTs. But that's just a chance of implementation detail.

Comment: Congrats to reaching 500k rep! You're not far from Jon Skeet!

Answer (score 7):

Let's make a simple diagram (addresses are made up):

```
Address                        Value
          +-----------------+
12345600  |  Obj variable   |  45680000
          +-----------------+
                   |
                   v
          +-----------------+
45680000  |     instance    |  
          |                 |
          |                 |
          +-----------------+
```

`Obj` is a variable. It is an object reference, which means it is actually a pointer to the instance.

If you take `@Obj`, you take the **address of the variable**. Its type is `Pointer`.

> So you get `@Obj = Pointer($12345600)`.

If you cast `Obj` to `Pointer` as `Pointer(Obj)`, you get the **address of the instance** to which the variable points. Its type is `Pointer` too.

> So you get `Pointer(Obj) = Pointer($45680000)`.

You can even test this:

```
if @Obj = Obj then
  Writeln('Same')
else
  Writeln('Different');
if Pointer(Obj) = Obj then
  Writeln('Same')
else
  Writeln('Different');
```

and you should get:

```
Different
Same
```

### EDIT

I changed `Object` to `Obj`, because `object` is a reserved word, in Delphi.

---

*More info in my article on pointers: [Addressing pointers](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html#objects).*

Comment: thank you so much for explanation and the link for you page, it is by far the most complete explanation that i've seen.

Answer (score 0):

`Pointer(Object)` is type cast, `@Object` is taking address of object. In other words `@Object` <> `Pointer(Object)`. When you using `Pointer(Object)`, you not getting pointer to Object, you getting raw pointer value.

Comment: No @Object is a double pointer, the address of a pointer to the object instance.

Comment: @David Heffernan and where says the opposite in my answer?

Comment: "When you using Pointer(Object), you not getting pointer to Object". That's wrong. Pointer(Object) is a pointer to the object instance. It is the address of the instance. Anyway it's really not clear. It's not clear when you use the word object whether you mean a variable or a general term for an instance of a class.

Comment: @David Heffernan You took the phrase out of context. And declared it wrong.

Comment: Actually, although I didn't downvote, my first reaction was similar to David's: your wording is not as clear as it could be.

Comment: Or this part. "`@Object` is taking address of object". That's wrong. It is the address of `Object` which in turn is itself the address of the object.